# Duplo Train Thomas?

Tags: duplo

Anyone know if Lego will make new Thomas And Friend Duplo?  The first sets were from 2005-2009 and I can't find any information about the future of this licences

Comment: For commercial reasons, TLG doesn't usually publish plans for their future lines. We can sometimes make an educated guess, but we can rarely know for sure.

Comment: I know, but there's always small leak about that kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Thomas and Friends license is [currently with Mega Bloks](http://www.megabloks.com/en-us/shop/construction-toys/thomas-and-friends) (as of January 2014). For now, that means Lego is not planning on producing any new sets.
[image]

However, it is not unheard of for licenses to switch. The Marvel Superheros license, for example, was with Mega Bloks as well until Lego took it over last year:
[image]

Comment: My eyessssssss!

Comment: So there's hope for LEGO to get Star Trek.  You know, after Star Wars ends.... yeah...

Comment: There's a [bit of the history here](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2241/56) - however I'm sure there was also some crossover with LEGO and MegaBloks, although that may have been more at the retailer level than officially.